# How do i introduce sufficient delay while using glutPostRedisplay() function in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

```
void display(void)

{

     char text1[10],text2[10];
     int i;
     glPointSize(2.0);
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      circle_draw(x1center,y1center,radius1);
      y1center-=5;
      while(y1center>=100)
      {
          glutPostRedisplay();
          y1center-=5;
      }
      glFlush();

}
```

I want to move the circle along the vertical axis.
But while using the glutPostRedisplay() function I can only see the initial and final positions of the circle. The transition is too fast to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void display(void)
{
     char text1[10],text2[10];
     int i;
     glPointSize(2.0);
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
     circle_draw(x1center,y1center,radius1);
     glFlush();
}

void update(int) { 
    if (y1center > 100) {
        y1center -= 5;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        glutTimerFunc(100, update, 0);
    }
}

int main() {
// ...

    glutTimerFunc(100, update, 0);

// ...
}
```

Comment: 571 C:\Dev-Cpp\include\GL\glut.h too few arguments to function `void glutTimerFunc(unsigned int, void (*)(int), int)'

Comment: I changed the update prototype to void update(int);                     And the function callback to glutTimerFunc(100,update,100);            But it still does not produce the desired result

Comment: Oops, yes, it's been a while since I used it. You need to add another call to `glutTimerFunc` inside of `update`. See updated code...